# No other errors except Extra argument in call Swift

Tags: swift

With this code, I am getting the error Extra Argument in call on Swift Xcode-beta.

```
self.blendShapeLabel.text = "The blendshapes are \((format: "%.2f"), eyeBlinkR),\((format: "%.2f"), eyeBlinkL),\((format: "%.2f"), eyeLookInL),\((format: "%.2f"), eyeLookInR),\((format: "%.2f"), eyeLookOutL),\((format: "%.2f"), eyeLookOutR),\((format: "%.2f"), eyeLookDownL),\((format: "%.2f"), eyeLookDownR),\((format: "%.2f"), eyeLookUpL),\((format: "%.2f"), eyeLookUpR),\((format: "%.2f"), eyeSquintL),\((format: "%.2f"), eyeWideL),\((format: "%.2f"), eyeSquintR),\((format: "%.2f"), eyeWideR),\((format: "%.2f"), mouthL),\((format: "%.2f"), mouthR),\((format: "%.2f"), mouthFrownL),\((format: "%.2f"), mouthFrownR),\((format: "%.2f"), mouthSmileL),\((format: "%.2f"), mouthSmileR),\((format: "%.2f"), mouthDimpleL),\((format: "%.2f"), mouthDimpleR),\((format: "%.2f"), mouthStretchL),\((format: "%.2f"), mouthStretchR),\((format: "%.2f"), mouthCloseCoeff),\((format: "%.2f"), mouthPucker),\((format: "%.2f"), mouthFunnel),\((format: "%.2f"), mouthRollLower),\((format: "%.2f"), mouthRollUpper),\((format: "%.2f"), mouthPressL),\((format: "%.2f"), mouthPressR),\((format: "%.2f"), mouthLowerDownL),\((format: "%.2f"), mouthLowerDownR),\((format: "%.2f"), mouthUpperUpL),\((format: "%.2f"), mouthUpperUpR),\((format: "%.2f"), jawForward),\((format: "%.2f"), jawLeft),\((format: "%.2f"), jawRight),\((format: "%.2f"), jawOpen),\((format: "%.2f"), cheekPuff),\((format: "%.2f"), cheekSquintL),\((format: "%.2f"), cheekSquintR),\((format: "%.2f"), noseSneerL),\((format: "%.2f"), noseSneerR),\((format: "%.2f"), tongueOut),\((format: "%.2f"), browInnerUp),\((format: "%.2f"), browDownL),\((format: "%.2f"), browDownR),\((format: "%.2f"), browOutterL),\((format: "%.2f"), browOutterR)."
```

Comment: You are trying to format too much data in one place, error seems very possible, you can debug and check if all fields are filled.

Comment: This line is a nightmare. I'd strongly suggest you break it up into smaller pieces.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of formatting you are trying to perform with your use of `format:`, instead I would suggest using `formatted()` with a `FormatStyle`

Assuming your values are of type `Double` we create a custom format style

```
let dec2: FloatFormatStyle<Double> = .number.precision(.fractionLength(2))
```

and then use it when creating the string (example shortened for brevity)

```
"The blendshapes are \(eyeBlinkR.formatted(dec2)),\(eyeBlinkL.formatted(dec2))."
```

Full example

```
let eyeBlinkR = 1.123
let eyeBlinkL = 1.456
let dec2: FloatFormatStyle<Float> = .number.precision(.fractionLength(2))
let out = "The blendshapes are \(eyeBlinkR.formatted(dec2)),\(eyeBlinkL.formatted(dec2))."

print(out)
```

> The blendshapes are 1.12,1.46.